# How to drop rows from a data frame if all columns equal to each other?

Tags: python, pandas

I understand how to drop rows if a given column is equal to some value e.g

```
df = df.drop(df[<some boolean condition>].index)
```

but how do you drop a row if the columns are all equal to each other? Is there a way to do this without specifying the column names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` method to loop through rows and make a logical series indicating if each contains unique values, and use boolean series to remove corresponding rows:

```
df[df.apply(lambda r: r.nunique() != 1, 1)]

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3,3,3,4,5], "B": [1,3,4,4,3,5,1]})
In [867]:

df[df.apply(lambda r: r.nunique() != 1, 1)]
Out[867]:
    A   B
1   2   3
2   3   4
3   3   4
5   4   5
6   5   1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just compare the first column against the entire df using [`.eq`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eq.html) and specify `axis=0` and call [`all`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.all.html#pandas.DataFrame.all) on the result and invert using `~`:

```
In [158]:
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':np.arange(5), 'b':[0,0,2,2,4]})
df

Out[158]:
   a  b
0  0  0
1  1  0
2  2  2
3  3  2
4  4  4

In [159]:    
df[~df.eq(df['a'], axis=0).all(axis=1)]

Out[159]:
   a  b
1  1  0
3  3  2
```

If you look at the boolean mask:

```
In [160]:
df.eq(df['a'], axis=0)

Out[160]:
      a      b
0  True   True
1  True  False
2  True   True
3  True  False
4  True   True
```

You can see it is true for the rows that meet the condition so calling `all(axis=1)` returns a 1-D boolean mask:

```
In [161]:
df.eq(df['a'], axis=0).all(axis=1)

Out[161]:
0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
dtype: bool
```